# Для каждого пользователя сделать одинаковый набор из 5 таблиц (пока пустых), связанных только с его id

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, авторизация, регистрация

Я создал базу с 5 таблицами. Сделал я их для обработки текста: табл-1) служит для поиска и замены; табл-2) находит имена собственные; табл-3) Оставляет только найденное значение из таблицы, а остальной текст удаляет и т.д. То есть, сами таблицы между собой никак не связаны. Таким же успехом, я могу создать одну таблицу вместо 5-ти...

Но теперь вдруг решил сделать регистрацию пользователей. У каждого пользователя будут 5 таких же таблиц, но свои. Каждый пользователь будет сам заполнять их по своему усмотрению после авторизации (разумеется, он видит только свои 5 таблиц).

Мне не хватает знаний и не могу разобраться, с какой стороны начать приступать. Теперь опишу, что я хочу увидеть. Пользователь зарегистрировался, авторизовался. Нажимает кнопку "Настройки" и видит уже готовые пять таблиц, но пока пустые. Заполнить ему их еще предстоит вручную. У второго и n-ого пользователя такая же картина.

С чего начать или какой порядок действий я должен предпринять, чтобы сделать задуманное? И второе. Как это должно выглядеть в phpmyadmin? То есть, я должен сделать таблицу `users` с пользователями (у каждого свой id), это понятно. А как прикрутить в phpmyadmin 5 таблиц к каждому пользователю (id пользователя и его уникальный набор из 5 таблиц). Пока плохо себе это представляю... Спасибо!

Comment: *У каждого пользователя будут 5 таких же таблиц, но свои.* Гм... а нафига? Одного набора достаточно, добавь просто в таблицы поле UserID.

Comment: @akina, давай на примере. Есть таблица FindReplace (id (здесь id - номер строки по сути), find_what, replace_with). Где здесь будет userId?

Comment: Почему "здесь"-то? Четвёртым полем.

Comment: Имеешь ввиду, что будет FindReplace(userId, id, find_what, replace_with)? И если у одного пользователя (к примеру, userId = 3) будет 80 строк, то в столбце userId будет 80 строк c цифрой "3"?

Comment: @forever_young Да, совершенно верно. во всех строках этого пользователя стоит его id. и когда будете работать со строками конкретного пользователя всегда будете указывать в where userId=3

Comment: Спасибо всем! Я себе все сложнее рисовал в голове

Comment: @Mike, как быть при выводе данных? Я имею ввиду, как вывести все столбцы без userID? Спасибо!